# Docker-compose attaching container hangs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lamp

I had no issues building the image or creating the container.

The attachement to the container is the problem, it seems to block and hang forever.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Docker-compose :
version: '3.7'
services:
    LAMP:
        build: ./Apache
        image : lamp_nzh:1
        container_name: lamp_nzh
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        tty: true
```

```
Docker File :
# Environnement Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Email du maintenair
MAINTAINER ZHITI Nicolas <nzhiti@gmail.com>

#Environnement 
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

# Mise Ã  jours du systÃ¨me
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -yqq
# Installation unzip
RUN apt-get install -yqq zip unzip

# Installation LAMP
RUN apt-get install -yqq \
    apache2 \
    php \
    libapache2-mod-php \
    mariadb-server \
    php-mysql 

# Installation modules 
RUN apt-get install php-curl php-gd php-intl php-json php-mbstring php-xml php-zip -yqq

# Port 80 (dans un premier temps)
EXPOSE 80

#Copies
COPY ./www/ /var/www/html/
COPY ./vhosts /etc/apache2/site-available
```

**Docker version :** Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

**Docker-compose version :** docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Edit : here is the docker-compose --verbose up, it seems it's a network issue.

```
Attaching to lamp_nzh
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=webserver', 'com.do                                                                                                               cker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.38/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.comp                                                                                                               ose.project%3Dwebserver%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7fe8dfd00710>
```

Comment: have you checked this issue? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3106

Comment: Yeah remooving the tty=true result in an exit code 0 error

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work with the docker-compose since my docker file is running fine with command :
 docker run -it -d -p 80:80 --name=example example:latest /bin/sh

Comment: @DrK Did you manage to come up with a solution for this?